# Are there native methods to include dynamic content in HTML?

Tags: html

You should never create html by concatenating strings `"<div>" + user_content + "</div>"` because `user_content` may include html tags that inject scripts leading to XSS attacks.

There are libraries that escape html in string, the DOM's javascript API allows safe content assignment with .textContent, but what about native html methods?

For instance, there could be an html element `text` that escapes all inner content and renders it as text. A `length` attribute would tell the parser to skip the next `length` characters.

```
`<div><text length="${user_content.length()}">` + user_content + "</text></div>"
```

For background, I'm writing an aws lambda function in javascript. It reads user data from dynamo and builds a simple web page. The lambda has no dependencies (except aws-sdk which is included in the lambda environment) and I'd like to keep it that way as a challenge. The page should not use javascript.

Can you write a javascript program that generates a safe html document, that does not use javascript, from untrusted input. Also, without using html entity encoding.

Comment: HTML has `<iframe>` to include some content. Your `"<div>" + user_content + "</div>"` is not HTML, but some programming language

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it was HTML. I'm talking about a server generating html. String methods are pretty universal so I didn't bother tagging this question with a language.